# Not able to iterate over lists with integer values - TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration

Tags: python

I'm trying to return a simple list `predict` from this method. `con1`, `con2`, `con3`, `con4` are lists with integer values 0 and 1.

```
def prediction():
    Volume_avg = []
    Volume_avg = movingavg(Volume_avg, F)
    m_Avg_price = []
    m_Avg_price = movingavg(m_Avg_price, C)
    con1 = con1_leaning(D, B, E)
    con2 = con2_leaning(D, B, m_Avg_price)
    con3 = con3_minvolume(F, Volume_avg)
    con4 = con4_minFluctuation(E, B, D)

    predict = []
    for i, j, k, l in zip(con1, con2, con3, con4):
        if i == j == k == l == 1:
            predict.append("up")
        elif i == j == 0 & k == l == 1:
            predict.append("down")
        else:
            predict.append("Can't say")

    return predict
```

However, when I try to run this code, I get an error as follows :

```
File "E:/Projects/Forecasting Trends/Forecast.py", line 117, in prediction
    for i, j, k, l in zip(con1, con2, con3, con4):
TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration
```

I'm trying to iterate over 1 and 0 values which are integers right? So why does it show an error that they aren't iterable? Would love it if somebody can let me know where I'm going wrong.

Edit : tried printing `con1` but it shows `None`. I'm not able to figure out why it says that? I have added the method `con1_leaning` as well. Here, `Lowprice`, `Highprice`, `Closeprice` are all lists with float values ( verified, this time)

```
def con1_leaning(Lowprice, Highprice, Closeprice):  # 1 if high, 0 if low
    con1_list = []
    for i, j, k in zip(Highprice, Closeprice, Lowprice):
        if float(i - j) < float(j - k):
            con1_list.append(1)
        else:
            con1_list.append(0)
    return con1_list
```

Comment: can you print `con1` for us and edit the question showing its contents?

Comment: `con1`, `con2`, `con3`, `con4` are iterable? Integers aren't iterable

Comment: @Abdulafaja lists of integer values like `[0, 1, 1, 1 ,...]`

Comment: @Ev.Kounis right, my bad

Comment: Can you add `print(type(con1), type(con2), type(con3), type(con4))` just before the loop and show us the output? I'm guessing one of these is not a list.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Okay there seems to be another issue there, it says "none" when I try to print it out. Guess `con1_leaning()` itself has an error, but I'm not sure why it says so.

Comment: @SastryGosukonda, please update the question with that info and the method formatted properly. It's a pain to read that in a comment.

Comment: @SastryGosukonda See? You debugged it yourself and it probably took you less time that posting in SO.

Comment: @iCart I tried printing what you suggested, the output is this : `<class 'list'> <class 'list'> <class 'list'> <class 'list'>`

Comment: @PavelGurkov I have edited the question again with the method formatted properly, my bad.

Comment: The `con1_learning` looks ok to me. What are you passing in there ? What are the D, B, E arguments? have you verified those? How does the `zip(Highprice, Closeprice, Lowprice)` look like in this case/>

Comment: I doubt there is a `return` statement in `con1_leaning`

Comment: And why is it `None` and not `[]`???

Comment: @Ev.Kounis D, B, E are again lists (verified) with floating point values. I wanna confirm something though. When I type `i-j` and `j-k` it operates on the subtraction result of the two floats right? Because that is the intention

Comment: @SastryGosukonda if D, B & E are lists with floating point values, you do not need to cast `i-j` to float but yes (`if i-j < j-k:`)

Comment: Thanks guys, it's printing what I wanted it to. I still don't know what made the difference though haha.